# Freeze a branch untill github action workflow in progress

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a way to freeze a branch while GHA workflow is in progress. Once GHA workflow completes then unfreeze.

Answer (score 0):

You can take inspiration from a GitHub Action like [Branch Protection Bot](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/branch-protection-bot) (and its [protection script](https://github.com/benjefferies/branch-protection-bot/blob/b6a1ef57a47860aa483bf6048c1e888018a15f9c/run.py#L10-L43)) to:

- add an initial step [protecting a branch](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches)
- add a final step removing that protection

That would in effect "freeze" the branch in that nobody would be able to contribute to it while the action workflow is running.